# Why my req.signedCookies shows undefined?

Tags: node.js, express

My cookie signed completely, but I call it in express by `req.signedCookie.sessionID` shows `undefined`

**Cart route file:**

```
router.post('/add-to-cart/:productID', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.signedCookies.sessionID); // undefined
});
```

**This is the image of my cookie in developer tool:**

[Cookie in google chrome developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbeeh.png)

**This is my server.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

require('dotenv').config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;

// Import Routes
const cartRoute = require('./routes/cart');

// Access localhost mongodb with mongoose
const url = process.env.DB_URL;
mongoose.connect(
  url,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  },
  () => {
    console.log('Connect to database success!');
  }
);

// Middleware
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const sessionMiddleware = require('./middleware/session');

// Route middelware
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use('/api/cart', cartRoute);

// Server listen at port ?
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at port: ${port}`);
});
```

**This is session middleware file which I sign cookie**

```
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.signedCookies.sessionID) { // Check if cookie exists, if not we will create new cookie with name: sessionID
    const sessionID = shortID.generate();
    res.cookie('sessionID', sessionID, {
      signed: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 8 * 3600000)
    });
  }

  next();
};
```